weird react behaviour that i recently noticed
I am working on a React component (FSRenderer) that fetches and transforms data, then renders a grid and a header. My issue is related to the loading state managed by Redux and how the rendering behaves.
Here’s what’s happening:

When data is being fetched and transformed, I set the Redux loading state to true using dispatch(setLoading(true)).

After the transformation is complete, I set the transformed data (transformedData), the transformed configuration (transformedConfig), and finally update the Redux loading state to false using dispatch(setLoading(false)).

However, I noticed that the loading state becomes false before the transformedData and transformedConfig are updated.

As a result, an additional render occurs where the grid briefly shows no data, despite the transformation being completed immediately afterward.



const [transformedData, setTransformedData] = useState<any[]>([]);
const [transformedConfig, setTransformedConfig] = useState<Object>({});
const gridRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            dispatch(setLoading(true)); 

            const data = await dmServices.getGridData();

            setTransformedData(data);
            setTransformedConfig(data);


            dispatch(setLoading(false)); // This seems to execute before `setTransformedData` and `setTransformedConfig`
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error while fetching and transforming data:', err);
            dispatch(setLoading(false));
        }
    })();
}, [module?.id, filters]);

return (
        <div>
      {transformedData.length > 0 && <Grid config={transformedConfig} data={transformedData} autosizeAllColumns={true} id='Grid' ref={gridRef} />}
      {transformedData.length == 0 && !gridLoading && <NoDataAvailable />}
        </div>
    );



is there any way to handle this? I can keep a local state variable for tracking loading, that will work fine. But I dont want to have 2 loading states- one in reducer and one local state

What are setTransformedData and setTransformedConfig? What do they do? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Hi, these are setter functions provided by useState(), edited it, please check

The basic gist is that enqueued React state updates are not immediately processed while the dispatched actions to a Redux store are immediately processed. They both trigger a component rerender, but because the Redux updates are processed first their updates trigger a rerender before the React state updates are processed and trigger their rerender.
After await dmServices.getGridData() there is nothing else in the callback function scope that is asynchronous, so the rest of the function body is processed synchronously.
Here's some example output logging of the actions and state updates:

// initial state
{gridLoading: false, transformedData: Array(0)}

// effect runs
dispatch loading true                           // <-- update Redux
{gridLoading: true, transformedData: Array(0)}  // <-- Redux store updated

// Got data
enqueue React state update                      // <-- update local State
dispatch loading false                          // <-- update Redux
{gridLoading: false, transformedData: Array(0)} // <-- Redux store updated
{gridLoading: false, transformedData: Array(1)} // <-- Local state updated


As a bit of a "hack" you can insert some additional asynchronous logic to allow React to process the enqueued state updates then dispatch actions to the store.
Example:
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true)); 

      const data = await dmServices.getGridData();

      setTransformedData(data);
      setTransformedConfig(data);

      // "Sleep" for the minimal amount of time and place the rest of
      // this function to the back of the event queue, allows above
      // React state updates to be processed first.
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 0);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error while fetching and transforming data:', err);
    } finally {
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    }
  })();
}, [module?.id, filters]);

Here's similar example output logging of the actions and state updates with the Redux updates pushed to the back of the event queue:

// initial state
{gridLoading: false, transformedData: Array(0)}

// effect runs
dispatch loading true                           // <-- update Redux
{gridLoading: true, transformedData: Array(0)}  // <-- Redux store updated

// Got data
enqueue React state update                      // <-- update local State
{gridLoading: true, transformedData: Array(1)}  // <-- Local state updated
dispatch loading false                          // <-- update Redux
{gridLoading: false, transformedData: Array(1)} // <-- Redux store updated



Thank you, this provided me with valuable insights.

@Meg Welcome, happy to help. Did this answer/address your question/issue?

yeah! it did helped with my confusion, although I wont be using this setTimeOut approach, need to find some other work around for this.

@Meg I think the timeout or any other similar hack/workaround will be necessary when working with local React state and the global Redux store. Have you considered moving/storing this fetched grid data also in the store? If so, then it's trivial to create an asynchronous action, e.g. a Thunk, to fetch the data, handle the loading state, and update the store grid data all exactly when you want in the order you want. If this is something that interests you can you edit your post to include your Redux setup?
